# order configurable product when out of stock

Tags: magento

I have to configure my magento store so that my customers can order configurable products when they are out of stock.
Because these products are out of stock, they do not appear on the products page.

I did find a way to show them the products page (system-->configuration-->inventory-->Display Out of Stock Products) but because the product is out of stock, the customer can't order it.

Anyone an idea on how to configure my site so the customer can buy out of stock configurable products?

I'm using Magento 1.5.0.1

Answer (score 1):

In Configuration > Inventory an option exits to display products out of stock.  This would be a good place to look.

EDIT:  Also if you want the ability for the customer to purchase the product you need to allow products to be back ordered in the following configuration tab.

Comment: I tried that, but because it's a configurable product, I can't allow it to be back ordered. 

I allowed back orders for all the simple products but that doesn't fix my problem

Comment: Are the simple products enabled? PS: Last time I read your question I am pretty sure you did not see you mention you tried the back order option.  In the future make note of your edits..

Comment: Sorry. It seems I forgot to mention I tried the backorder option.
Anyway, all the simple products are enabled but it's stil not working